# Android webpage 'audio notification' next button

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, audio, notifications

I'm trying to add a next (or even previous) button to the notification Chrome will show on a Android (or even Apple) device when you are playing audio on a website (in the background). Clicking the button should fire a link or a JS function.

See below screenshot, I am using this code:

```
<audio controls autoplay onended="myFunction()">
<source src="<?php echo 'http://www.music.*****.com/music/' . $_GET['file']; ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

[Screenshot from Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxqxV.png)

If this is not possible, perhaps there is an easy way to make an app that can do this and fetch mp3's over http. I really just need a working solution, efficiency and looks are secondary as I am using this together with some friends only.

Thanks!